# Trying to resolve an issue with returning points scores for teams

Tags: java

After updating my question I know only get 0 points per team the recursion problem has been erased, any ideas on how to solve this issue.

After updating my question I know only get 0 points per team the recursion problem has been erased, any ideas on how to solve this issue.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String homeside;
    String awayside;
    int homesidescore;
    int awaysidescore;

    homeside = "liverpool";
    awayside = "Chelsea";
    homesidescore = 0;
    awaysidescore = 3;
    int teamPoints = 0;



    winnerIs(homeside, homesidescore, teamPoints, awayside,   awaysidescore);
    team1points(teamPoints);
    team2points(teamPoints);
    System.out.println(team1points(teamPoints));
    System.out.println(team2points(teamPoints));
```

}

```
 public static int winnerIs(String team1, int team1Score, int points, String team2, int team2Score){
    int pointtoreturn=0;
    if (team1Score > team2Score){
        System.out.println("the winner is " + team1);


    pointtoreturn= points +1;}

    else if (team1Score == team2Score){
        System.out.println("it is a draw");
        pointtoreturn= points +3;}

    else if (team1Score < team2Score){
        System.out.println("the winner is " + team2);
        pointtoreturn= points +2;}
        return pointtoreturn;

     }

 public static int team1points(int points){
     int p=0;
      if (points == 1){

         p= team1points(+3);
     }
     else if(points == 2){

          p= team1points(+0);

    }
    else if(points == 3){

        p= team1points(+1);
    }
    return p;}



 public static int team2points(int points){
     int p=0;
    if (points == 1){

        p= team2points(+0);
    }
    else if(points == 2){

        p= team2points(+0);

    }
    else if(points == 3){

        p= team2points(+3);
    }
    return p;}

    //Any advice would be great
```

Comment: do you know that you are using recursive calls?

Comment: You will have an infinite loop in your code if you call `team1points(1)`. So you may refactor your code

Comment: I cant see any other way to solve the problem, is there an easier way?

Comment: So my code could get caught in an endless loop.

Comment: So its looping until it gets to -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using recursive calls? For example, `return team1points(+3);` is a recursive call, you should just `return 3`.

Also you are not saving the result from `winnerIs`, you should use `teamPoints = winnerIs(...);`

To return more parameters from a method you could return a class that contains your result, for example

```
public class Points {

    private int points1;
    private int points2;

    public Points(int points1, int points2) {
        this.points1 = points1;
        this.points2 = points2;
    }

    public int getPoints1() {
        return points1;
    }

    public int getPoints2() {
        return points2;
    }
}
```

And then `winnerIs` create and return this `Points` object.

In main the call would look like this:

```
Points points = winnerIs(homeside, homesidescore, teamPoints, awayside, awaysidescore);
System.out.println(points.getPoints1());
System.out.println(points.getPoints2());
```

Answer (score 0):

`teamPoints` is never getting updated in your `main` method.  Since your conditionals are only for handling points values one through three, that is the reason you are getting a -1 returned.  It appears the root issue is the result of `winnerIs()` is not getting assigned to anything

Answer (score 0):

Your team1points and team2points are both tale-recursive. Your only base case is

```
return -1;
```

so, whatever result might be constructed in the recursive calls, they would disappear because you will always return -1 whenever the function stops.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your help guys, here is my final version and it works great, i have learn't a lot from this exercise and all of your instructions have been hugely beneficial, kind regards David.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String homeside;
        String awayside;
        int homesidescore;
        int awaysidescore;

        homeside = "liverpool";
        awayside = "Chelsea";
        homesidescore = 1;
        awaysidescore = 1;
        int teamPoints = winnerIs(homeside, homesidescore, awayside, awaysidescore);

        team1points(teamPoints);
        team2points(teamPoints);
        System.out.println(team1points(teamPoints));
        System.out.println(team2points(teamPoints));

    }

    public static int winnerIs(String team1, int team1Score, String team2, int team2Score) {


        if (team1Score > team2Score) {
            System.out.println("the winner is " + team1);


            return 1;
        } else if (team1Score == team2Score) {
            System.out.println("it is a draw");
            return 3;
        } else if (team1Score < team2Score) {
            System.out.println("the winner is " + team2);
            return 2;
        }
        return 0;

    }

    public static int team1points(int points) {

        if (points == 1) {

            return +3;
        } else if (points == 2) {

            return +0;

        } else if (points == 3) {

            return +1;
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static int team2points(int points) {

        if (points == 1) {

            return +0;
        } else if (points == 2) {

            return +3;

        } else if (points == 3) {

            return +1;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String homeside;
        String awayside;
        int homesidescore;
        int awaysidescore;

        homeside = "liverpool";
        awayside = "Chelsea";
        homesidescore = 0;
        awaysidescore = 3;
        int teamPoints = 0;



        winnerIs(homeside, homesidescore, teamPoints, awayside,   awaysidescore);
        team1points(teamPoints);
        team2points(teamPoints);
        System.out.println(team1points(teamPoints));
        System.out.println(team2points(teamPoints));

    }

    public static int winnerIs(String team1, int team1Score, int points, String team2, int team2Score){
        int pointtoreturn=0;
        if (team1Score > team2Score){
            System.out.println("the winner is " + team1);


        pointtoreturn= points +1;}

        else if (team1Score == team2Score){
            System.out.println("it is a draw");
           pointtoreturn= points +3;}

        else if (team1Score < team2Score){
            System.out.println("the winner is " + team2);
            pointtoreturn= points +2;}
            return pointtoreturn;

     }

     public static int team1points(int points){
         int p=0;
         if (points == 1){

             p= team1points(+3);
        }
        else if(points == 2){

             p= team1points(+0);

        }
        else if(points == 3){

            p= team1points(+1);
        }
        return p;}



     public static int team2points(int points){
         int p=0;
        if (points == 1){

            p= team2points(+0);
        }
        else if(points == 2){

            p= team2points(+0);

        }
        else if(points == 3){

            p= team2points(+3);
        }
        return p;}
}
```

Comment: This returns 0 points for each team regardless of the scores. The code looks a lot better though